# tableViewCell is not updating the data, but instead appending the newly fetched data to the previous one

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am trying the reload and update the `UITableviewCell` on `UICollectionViewCell` didSelect delegate, I expect the `UITableviewCell` to be updated according to the values returned by the `UICollectionViewCell` selection. `UICollectionViewCell` returns the `data` as expected, however, `UITableviewCell` is not updating and reloading the data but instead, keeps appending the data to the previous one on scrolling, like when i click the "shoes" shoes is returned, and if i click the "hat" hat is being appended to "shoes" data instead of being displayed as a separate data type.

I am updating my `UITableviewCell` from the `UICollectionViewCell` `didSelect` delegate, (I am hitting the api from there)

Api hit:

```
//MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // SET CATEGORY PARAMETER VALUES
        let item = self.type[indexPath.row]
        switch item.type {
        case .shoe:
            self.type[getIndex(type: .shoe)].category = "shoe"
            self.type[getIndex(type: .shoe)].subCategory = "men"
            
            self.category = self.type[getIndex(type: .shoe)].category
            self.subCategory = self.type[getIndex(type: .shoe)].subCategory
           
            apiCall(categoryKey: self.category!, subCategoryKey: self.subCategory!)
            print(category!,subCategory!)
        case .hat:
            self.type[getIndex(type: .hat)].category = "hat"
            self.type[getIndex(type: .hat)].subCategory = "men"
            
            self.category = self.type[getIndex(type: .hat)].category
            self.subCategory = self.type[getIndex(type: .hat)].subCategory
            
            apiCall(categoryKey: self.category!, subCategoryKey: self.subCategory!)
            print(category!,subCategory!)
       
        }
    }
}
```

- apiCall func:

```
    func apiCall(categoryKey: String, subCategoryKey: String) {
        if (page == 0) {
            data = []
            hasMore = false
        }
        guard let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "accessToken") else {return}
        
        MyAPI.getData(token: token, limit: limit, skip: skip, category: categoryKey, subCategory: subCategoryKey, completion: { (response) in
            
            self.hasMore = response.hasMore!
            self.page += 1
            self.skip += self.limit
            self.data.append(contentsOf: response.items)
            
            if let total = response.totalCount {
                self.totalCount = total
            } else {
                self.totalCount = 0
            }
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        })
    }
```

my  tableView not displaying different data on different cell selection, rather appending them to each other, what am i doing wrong here?
(btw, there are issues with the pagination also, somehow data is not correctly paginating to different datas).. .

Comment: @matt, I did, I googled for it and tried many ways but still cannot make it work. can you check my code, and find any bad logic or bad smell over there?

Comment: @zeytin, yeah bro you are right in deed.. i appreciate your help much, the reason i deleted the question was that I realized that my qustion contents were wrong, so i updated the question. sorry tho.

Comment: You should add more details regarding of where your collectionView and tableView are. Also, add an image of the result you get, because it is not clear what is wrong